# Different behavior for get_object_vars between PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.2

Tags: php

The following code returns different output when tested with PHP 7.0 and 7.2.

```
$array = simplexml_load_string("<test>
</test>") ;

print_r(get_object_vars($array));
```

For PHP 7.0, it prints:

```
 Array
(
)
```

For PHP 7.2, it prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 

)
```

What is the cause of this difference? Any suggestions on how to make version 7.2 behave like 7.0 in this case?

*** Update ***
As per https://3v4l.org/NHV9v, the behavior is the same for version 5.0.0 - 7.1.33, 7.4.0 - 7.4.4, and different for version 7.2.0 - 7.3.16.

Comment: See the duplicate question. 7.0 and 7.1 had a bug, it was fixed in 7.2.

Comment: The 7.1 output is wrong, it's missing the `0` property that should be there.